# Two OwnCloud instances on the same server

Tags: linux, encryption, owncloud

I want to keep my data in OwnCloud both in encrypted and (more sensitive data) in encrypted form. As far as I know, OwnCloud can encrypt "all or nothing" in particular instance. Because of that, I want to have two OC instances on the same physical server.
How can I configure Apache server and OwnCloud itself to operate with two instances? Any example?
I use OwnCloud ver 6.0.4 on Mageia ver 3 server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to keep two different Virtual Hosts, with two diferent databases and two different owncloud data directories.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
           ServerName secure-owncloud.your-domain
           DocumentRoot /var/www/secure-owncloud
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName insecure-owncloud.your-domain
           DocumentRoot /var/www/insecure-owncloud
</VirtualHost>
```

You should also add https configuration, and make sure each owncloud (secure and insecure) has different data-dir (ej. /var/insecure-data-dir and /var/secure-data-dir)